# if it is not bug then why there is no output

Tags: php, debugging

I declared class which has 1 object . calling method with that object is okay , but calling methods which was not-an-object causing no output .. here it demonstrates

```
    
                // defining simple class
            class Person{ 
            function say_hello($name='world')
                {
                    echo "hello {$name}";
```

```
            }
        }

        $instant1 = new Person();

        $object2 = new Person();

        echo get_class($object2);
        ?>
<br/>
<?php 

if(is_a($object2,'Person'))
{
//remeber to pass arguments 
echo "This object or instant is in that class";
}
else {

echo "No dude :( ";
}

?>



<?php 


$instant1->say_hello('Paritosh');

echo " <br/>";
```

$ob->say_hello(); // No error No output , even there is no object with name $ob and below code is not running
                      // is it bug or any concept ?

echo "No output ";
    $object2->say_hello();

```
?>
```

I'm using PHP Version 5.2.17 in IIS Express in webmatrix platform .

Comment: Change the PHP error level to show errors, warnings

Comment: @shakti : that's not an issue . My question is why there is no output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ob ist not a Person, so how should the interpreter know that you want access Person?
if you want to access the function without an object, try:

```
Person::say_hello();
```

Comment: that's what i am saying .. Interpreter must throw error or just ignore that line .. but why there is no echo which is written below that line .     echo "No output ";

    $object2->say_hello();  //no output

Comment: it is just not showing the error, see shaktis comment on you question to enable that. The error should be something like "object ob has no method..."

Comment: i agree what you are saying but why there is no output which was written below that line .

Comment: this happens. It might still have to do with this settings! So the code is executed, and at some point there is an error, but it is not shown because of the settings. But obviously the code crashed on the error so everything after the error wont show.

Comment: so i can say that whenever there is runtime error , php execution stops . right ? this is what you mean.. indirectly

Comment: yes, and if you fix the settings than you will see the error and it is clear where it stopped. As you see it can be very confusing if it crashes somewhere in the middle and you dont even know there was an error.